# Born-Infeld equation with a coefficient: which phenomena it describes?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, non-linear-systems

Let us consider the well known Born-Infeld equation
$$-{\rm div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{b^2}|\nabla u|^2}}\right) =g(u).$$
It appears quite naturally in several fields such as electromagnetism, relativity and so on.

My question is: if we consider the previous equation involving a coefficient which depend on the solution itself $A(u)$, I mean
$$-{\rm div}\left(\frac{A(u)\nabla u}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{b^2}|\nabla u|^2}}\right) =g(u),$$
what kinds of phenomena does it describe? Could someone please tell me something? (you can also consider, for simplicity, $b=1$).

Comment: Why do you expect this to describe any particular system, as opposed to being one of an infinite number of "random" equations without a physical interpretation?

Comment: Actually, I hope it describes some known phenomenon, but with any particular expectation.

Comment: Why are you writing $g(u)$ in the rhs? The meaning of the rhs is the charge density, it should depend on coordinates. Assumption that it depends only on the potential makes no sense to me.